# How to move wordpress website from hosting account to localhost

Tags: htaccess, apache

I'm getting 404 error while accessing relative paths on 
*Wordpress* website copied from hosting and deployed locally as *Apache* vhost.

Local website is basically *git clone* of the existing remote website.

The following steps were performed to make it work:

- DB urls were searched and replaced with [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org) to be http://local.webiste.com
- VHost configured according to apache documentation.
- */etc/hosts* modified.

So website can be accessed successfully via http://local.website.com. 
Media in *http://local.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017* can be viewed successfully.

Though, accessing a *Wordrpess* page identified by /relative path (relative to current domain/site) causes **"The requested URL /relative/ was not found on this server" error**.

I'm using the same .*htaccess* from the remote *public_html* folder.

How to achive equivalent to hosting behaviour for local vhost website?

Is *.htaccess, apache2* configuration, *vhost* configurations should be changed?

Comment: First thing to try is go back and use a database migration plugin. Just search-and-replace is likely to cause issues because WP stores so much serialized data. Second thing to try: delete .htaccess, log in, and visit your permalink settings page to regenerate the default WP .htaccess. Then make sure to open an Incognito window or clear browser cache & restart browser to check if it's fixed.

Comment: Your local url is potentially spelled incorrectly, depending on how you did it...  Unless that's the way it's supposed to be.. website should have the I and S switched around: http://local.website.com  Probably not your issue, but figured I'd point it out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to allow using *.htaccess* in */etc/apache/apache2.conf* by changing from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.
More about it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

So that section related to my local website now looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/local.webiste.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```